# How to push a javascript dictionary to a multidimensional array or another dictionary?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I'm new in javascript development.
I've got something like that:

```
var array1=[];
array1[0][0]={};
var dic={'title':'111','url':'222'};
array1[0][0]=dic;
```

But it didn't work?
what's the problem?
How can I push a dictionary to a multidimensional array or another dictionary?

Answer (score 5):

You skipped a step:

```
var array1 = [[]];
array1[0][0] = {};
```

Your declaration just makes a one-dimensional array (well, all arrays in JavaScript are one-dimensional). In the version above, I create a one-dimensional array and initialize it to contain another one-dimensional array.

It might be clearer like this:

```
var array1 = [];
array1[0] = [];
array1[0][0] =  {};
```

If you don't put another array in the first spot in the first array, then that attempt to reference it in the assignment that follows will fail. This statement:

```
array1[0][0] = {};
```

involves *fetching* the value of `array1[0]` so that it can, in turn, be used as an array.  Because you didn't put an array there, that statement would cause an exception.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because `array1[0]` is `undefined` (because there is no element with such index) and `undefined` is not array or object, it has not any property and you cannot assign valye for some property.